# The movie "Seven Pounds": what does "pounds" mean here?

Tags: cinema

In our language (Ukraine) - it translated as 7 lives, pound as I know is a unit of weight or monetary unit, how is it related? Does it have anything similar to life? Or it is just a translation of our country?

Comment: AFAIK the "7 pounds" in the movie referred to the combined weight of the donated organs.

Comment: The film affects seven lives, so the translation is fine. Not every perfect translation makes a good title.

Comment: It is probably not pure serendipity that there are 7 pounds, and 7 lives. However, it has been noted elsewhere that the _actual_ weight of the organs donated in the movie do not really sum up to seven pounds...

Comment: Note that there is the idiom "pound of flesh".  There may be a metaphorical linkage to this.

Answer (score 3):

This is apparently alluding to Shakespeares "Merchant of Venice", were a debtor owes a pound of flesh - and since the protagonist in the movie is "paying back" seven lives, it's seven pounds.

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Pounds), Will Smith confirmed the connection:

> Will Smith is reported to have confirmed that the title refers to
> Shakespeare's The Merchant of Venice, in which a debtor must pay a
> pound of flesh

While, being a Shakespeare fan, that was basically the first thing I thought of, I don't think it makes a lot of sense, since nothing in the circumstances of the debt in the play is even remotely parallel to what happens in the movie. But if the main actor/producer confirms it, then that's probably it.

Comment: Many of the idioms that derive from Shakespeare no longer refer directly to the original plots.